# NoSuchMethodError in Spark-NLP on Databricks

Tags: databricks

Good morning.

I'm running spark-nlp 5.1.4 on Databricks 14.1 ML runtime (spark 3.5.0, scala 2.12.0, GPU).

I can download bert_embeddings_bge_large just fine but I'm getting this NoSuchMethodError from the attached code. A previous cell is running a spark-nlp pipeline ok.

I saw on stack overflow someone had the same issue a few weeks ago...they solved it by downgrading to spark-nlp 4.4.2, which is not a solution for me (I want to use DocumentCharacterTextSplitter and bert_embeddings_bge_large for example).

I tried downgrading spark-nlp and associated dependencies to 5.1.0 and then to 4.4.2 but I need to use DocumentCharacterTextSplitter and bert_embeddings_bge_large so need 5.1.0+.

As always, I'd be grateful for any ideas.  Keith

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iqwz.png)

```
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from sparknlp.common import *
from sparknlp.base import *

documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler() \
    .setInputCol("text") \
    .setOutputCol("document")

tokenizer = Tokenizer() \
    .setInputCols(["document"]) \
    .setOutputCol("token")

bert_loaded = 
BertEmbeddings.pretrained("bert_embeddings_bge_large","en") \
    .setInputCols(["document", "token"]) \
    .setOutputCol("embeddings") \
    .setCaseSensitive(True)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[documentAssembler, tokenizer, 
bert_loaded])

data = spark.createDataFrame([["I love Spark 
NLP"]]).toDF("text")

# result = pipeline.fit(data).transform(data)

model = pipeline.fit(data)

predictionDF = model.transform(data)
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iqwz.png)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: In Databricks, I downgraded Spark version from 3.5.0 to 3.3.2 and this resolved the issue. This required switching to DBR 12.2 ML (spark 3.3.2, scala 2.12, GPU).

Also, because Databricks Runtime 12.2 does not support the storing of Assembly JARs in Volumes, I stored the JAR in DBFS for installation in the cluster library